# Not sure why this JavaScript function is not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am writing JavaScript / HTML for a project for one of my classes. I'm not sure why the JavaScript function won't execute. The first return ("result") works no problem but for some reason my program wont work for ("result2"). I pasted the function down below:

```
function multiplyBy(){
var x = document.getElementById("text").value;
var y = document.getElementById("text2").value;
var z = x * y;
var a = 52 * z;
var b = paraseFloat(a);

if (b > 20000) {
    output = "The Salary is too little."
}
if else (b < 20000; b > 25000) {
    output = "The Salary is almost enough. Let's negotiate."
}
else {
    output = "This is a great salary for me."
}

return document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The Salary is: " + b;
return document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = output
}
```

Comment: Try doing parseInt around the document.getElementById and also you have a typo on var b paraseFloat when it should be parseFloat

Comment: Some typos are found in the code, for instance, `paraseFloat` should be `parseFloat`, and `if else` should be `else if`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few issues in the code

`paraseFloat` is a miss type it should be `parseFloat`

```
if else (b < 20000; b > 25000) {
```

`if else` should be `else if`
if you want to have a range in your check you need to add logical operators like `&& ||`

and the you need to review the logic for checking the salary i am not sure but i have changed something that "has" some sense

you can check in here

```js
function multiplyBy() {
  var x = document.getElementById("text").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("text2").value;
  var z = x * y;
  var a = 52 * z;
  var b = parseFloat(a);

  if (b < 20000) {
    output = "The Salary is too little.";
  } else if (b >= 20000 && b < 25000) {
    output = "The Salary is almost enough. Let's negotiate.";
  } else {
    output = "This is a great salary for me.";
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The Salary is: " + b;
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = output;
}
multiplyBy();
```

```html
<input type='text' name='text' id='text' value=10 />
<input type='text' name='text2' id='text2' value=10 />

<div id='result'></div>
<div id='result2'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found couple of issues in your code but you were almost there. Let me summarize in few steps where it was wrong:

1. In your code `if else` was presented. Using `else if` works other way around, read further [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).
2. Logical AND operator for defining between values for salary works differently, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND) you can find details. `b < 20000; b > 25000` is just wrongly defined, I have corrected to have `b >= 20000 && b < 25000`. Solution uses `&&` and changed a bit the condition.
3. In parsing to float case there was a typo in your function call, should have `parseFloat` instead of `paraseFloat`. Read further [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
4. Just changed from `b < 20000` to `b > 20000` which makes more sense in terms of text result.
5. And lastly, in your function there are 2 return statements, even if there is no need at all in that code. The function manipulates the DOM then it will automatically return `undefined`. Please find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) the documentation for more details which states:

> A function without a return statement will return a default value. ... For all other functions, the default return value is undefined.

And finally here is a working solution:

```js
function multiplyBy() {
  const x = document.getElementById("text").value;
  const y = document.getElementById("text2").value;
  const z = x * y;
  const a = 52 * z;
  const b = parseFloat(a);

  if (b < 20000) {
      output = "The Salary is too little.";
  } else if (b >= 20000 && b < 25000) {
      output = "The Salary is almost enough. Let's negotiate.";
  } else {
      output = "This is a great salary for me.";
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The Salary is: " + b;
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<input id="text" />
<input id="text2" />

<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>

<button onclick="multiplyBy()">Calculate</button>
```

Additionally it is worth to read further about when to use `const`, `let` and `var`.

Hope this helps!